# Factory of Func Delegate

Tags: c#, function, design-patterns, lambda, architecture

I am trying to figure out a way using which I could get a business function as a Func. I am trying to write business logic as a pure function so that based on the requirement my provider or factory could return me just that piece of business logic rather than the entire object which has methods that I don't need for certain code logic flow.

```
public static Func<IArgs, IOut> GetFunc()
{
    return new Func<IArgs, IOut>((DataParams p) => new OutObject());
}
```

The issue is that even though DataParams and OutObject are implementing IArgs and IOut, the compiler warns me of an implicit casting error. Making the interfaces covariant with T makes it hard for me to figure out how should I implement this.

Primary Objective - I want to write a factory that throws out functions that take objects(more derived types) holding a different set of parameters to be passed as Get-Set properties. This function would return me an object after it processes the data based on the parameter passed. I want to make the consumer aware of which derived type object the function is expecting as the parameter.

```
public static Func<IArgs, IOut> GetFunc(processor p)
{
    Func<IArgs, IOut> f = default;
    switch (p)
    {
        case processor.DoWork:
            f = (p) => new OutObject(); //P is cat derived from IArgs
            break;


        case processor.FooWork:
            f = (p) => new SomeOutObject(); //P is dog derived from IArgs
            break;
      }
      return f;
 }
```

Comment: Current interface is Invariant, make the following change to the Func definition, `Func<in IArgs, out IOut>` to make it co-variance compliant and the warnings will be tided away

Comment: Is that something you can do in C# 8 ?

Comment: No much before it, I think C# 2 / C# 3 has co-variance introduced

Comment: This is possible for delegates and Interfaces. However, I am trying to return the function as is. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: You are returning a Func delegate, which needs to be Co-Variant. Please understand there's no way to return function W/o a Delegate (Function pointer)

Comment: Since I am already using a Func delegate, IArgs in implicitly contra-variant and IOut is covariant. Explicitly putting in and out keywords gives me an error. Could you please send me a sample of what are referring to.

Comment: Ok this is my mistake, but what the compilation error suggest is the fundamental mistake in using the generics. It would be good if you could paste the code snippet, nonetheless let me post a reference for more clarity. This issue is not about Covariance and Contravariance, but generics usage

Comment: Please review the code underneath, this shall be similar to what you are trying to achieve, let me know and modify your question with code, if you are trying to solve a different problem altogether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the code underneath, this is in my view is similar to what you are trying:

```
namespace LibGeneric
{
    public interface IArgs {  }     

    public interface IOut { }

     public class LibClassGeneric<TArgs,TOut>
     where TArgs:IArgs
     where TOut:IOut
     {
            public static Func<TArgs,TOut> GetFunc()
            {
                return (DataParams p) => new OutObject();
            }

    }

    public class DataParams : IArgs  { }

    public class OutObject : IOut  { }

}
```

Following line is a compilation error due to following reason:

`return (DataParams p) => new OutObject();`

- There's no type compatibility between `TArgs, DataParams` and `TOut,OutObject`
- What you are trying to do is if base interface or class is same, then two types can be assigned to other, which is not correct
- For a Generic function / Func Delegate to compile, you need to assign it something that takes `TArgs` as input and `TOut` as Output, now they have constraints to be verified that you cannot add any code at compile time which doesn't align with the constraint.
- It is only when you are calling the `Func<TArgs,TOut> GetFunc()` you should be able to fill in the `DataParams` and `OutObject`, not while defining the generic definition

> **Now review this definition of the Generic code:**

```
public class LibClassGeneric<TArgs,TOut>
     where TArgs:IArgs
     where TOut:IOut
     {
             public static Func<TArgs,TOut> GetFunc(TOut o)
             {
               return (args) => o;
             }        
    }
```

- This will compile, since you are referring to the correct Types in the method definition
- This is how you can utilize it:

  ```
   DataParams d = new DataParams();
   OutObject o = new OutObject();
   var resultFunc  = LibClassGeneric<DataParams,OutObject>.GetFunc(o); // Call Func
   resultFunc(d); // Invocation
  ```
- Now you add any level of complexity while calling and Invoking the `GetFunc()`, till the point type parameter matches

> **Edit 1:**

Following is the code provided by OP:

```
public static Func<IArgs, IOut> GetFunc(Processor p)
        {

        Func<IArgs, IOut> f = default;

        switch (p)
        {
            case Processor.DoWork:
                f = (p) => new OutObject(); //P is cat derived from IArgs
                break;


            case Processor.FooWork:
                f = (p) => new OutObject(); //P is dog derived from IArgs
                break;
            }
            return f;
        }
```

This Code returns a func delegate with `IArgs` as Input and `IOut` as output, which being Contravariant and Covariant compliant allows to provide a parameter as derived class of `IArgs` and result could be derived class of `IOut`, it can simple be called using a call as follows:

```
  var func = GetFunc(Processor.DoWork);
  var result = func(new Dog());
```

Now the `result` type is `IOut` and needs typecasting to the actual type, there's no way to change it except the probing the exact type via reflection or doing the static type casting

Comment: The Func delegate in my original question has specific interface type and not generic TArgs, TOut. I have modified the question to make it more clear what exactly I am looking for.

Comment: Code that you have compiles without an issue, that doesn't explain the issue you are referring to, till the point you  have input and output derived from IArgs and IOut. If you have base type to be supplied as a input parameter, then any kind of derived parameter will fill in, please explain the issue clearly, there's no compilation error that you have mentioned earlier

Comment: On the same basis as GetFunc(), I just want the consumer to be aware of what derived type object needs to passed as parameter while invoking the actual function. Have a look at the added code in the question, that should brighten up the idea.

Comment: Your added code doesn't provide any additional information, I am not even what exactly is the issue now, you can simple call `GetFunc`, get a func delegate as return, where you can supply any child class of IArgs and return could be any derived class of IOut. What do you mean by awareness, here, caller shall just know which are derived classes, delegate implements Contra and Co Variance. If there's really an issue then highlight it, currently I see none

Comment: Check the **Edit 1** of my answer, that may help to an extent, there's no way to avoid type casting in this case

Comment: The Edit 1 is something I was looking for. Appreciate your patience.

Comment: Glad it helped, Please try to be specific in the question itself, you will get a faster response. Please see if you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: wanted to see if someone else wants to pour in their inputs, otherwise will do.